# Defining a proxy for a member function that takes a member function pointer as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am using a third-party library with a class that that is declared like this:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
class Delegate<Ret(Args...)>
{
  // ...
};
```

and it has some template member function that have 2 template parameters. The first parameter is the class type, and the second parameter is the member function pointer:

```
template<typename Class, Ret(Class:: *Member)(Args...) const>
void connect(Class *instance);

template<typename Class, Ret(Class:: *Member)(Args...)>
void connect(Class *instance);
```

It is then used like this:

```
class A
{
  void f(int)
  { }

  void foo()
  {
    Delegate<void(int)> d;
    d.connect<A, &A::f>(this);
  }
};
```

I would like to create a proxy template function `MyConnect` that simply forwards the arguments to `Delegate's` `connect`

```
class A
{
  void f(int)
  { }

  void foo()
  {
    MyConnect<A, &A::f>(this);
  }

  template <???>
  void MyConnect(???)
  {
    Delegate<void(int)> d;
    d.connect<???, ???>(this);
  } 
};
```

I cannot do this `template <typename Class, void(Class::*Member)(int)>` because I do not know what the return type is nor do I know the number of function arguments

Comment: *"I do not know what the return type is nor do I know the number of function arguments"*. How to you create `Delegate` type then?

Comment: I know it there, but the proxy is a utility function that is part of our framework and thus I cannot know the return type or the arguments ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++17, you might use `auto`:

```cpp
template <typename C, auto m>
void MyConnect()
{
    Delegate<void(int)> d;
    d.connect<C, m>(this);
}
```

Comment: As luck would have it, we are using `C++17` and this worked very well. Thank you!